# Extract substring and change cell value using Mid and Find in Excel (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop through a column and extract a substring within each cell (in my example, the "Code:")

[image]

I want to loop through each cell and run the formula in place. Basically delete everything in each cell of the column, except the Code.

I know how to extract the string into another column B using the formula: 
=MID(A2,FIND("Code:",A2,1),23)

...but I want to do it in the same cell.I tried this code in vba, but don't know what I am doing wrong:

`For Each cell In Range("A:A")
    cell.Value = Mid(.Value, InStr(1, .Value, "Code:"), 23)
Next`

Comment: Why **23** characters rather than **14** ??

Comment: Unless you're using a `With` block outside of the `for` loop, one possible problem is that your `.Value` references aren't going where you think they're going. Try `cell.Value = Mid(cell.Value, InStr(1, cell.Value, "Code:"), 23)`

Comment: Does "Code:" exist in **EVERY** cell in column A?  `Instr` will return 0 if it doesn't exist (and I can't believe that you really have 1048576 cells with the string "Code:" in them) and a `Mid` starting at character position 0 will fail.  (Plus what PeterT said!)

Comment: Ah I see!! no theres blank cells after A100 or so.. How do I run this formula just on the non blank cells?

Comment: I changed it to "cell.value" and it still doesnt work. mybe the InStr returning 0 is the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two main errors in your code:

- the use of `.Value` without a `With` block to define which object it was the `Value` of (as pointed out by PeterT in a comment), and
- trying to process **every** cell in column A, many (most?) of which would not contain any value at all, and definitely not the string you were looking for.

Refactored code:

```
Dim CodeExists As Long
'Only run the loop across cells that contain data:
For Each cell In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    With cell
        CodeExists = InStr(1, .Value, "Code:")
        'Check that "Code:" exists
        If CodeExists > 0
            .Value = Mid(.Value, CodeExists, 23)
        End If
    End With
Next
```

---

And, as Gary's Student asked, why are you using 23?  "Code: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" is 20 characters long, not 23, so you are grabbing 3 more characters than I would think you would be after.

P.S.  If you don't even want the "Code: " to be left in the final result, you can change your `Mid` statement to:

```
            .Value = Mid(.Value, CodeExists + 6, 14)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great! For the 23 question, Im not sure! this was trial and error. I thought it would be 20 too. but it only worked with 23!

I also did want to not have "code", and your solution worked perfectly !!